# Lua c-api: How to identify the coroutine/thread involved in a lua_pushcclosure callback?

Tags: c++, c, lua, lua-5.2

Is there a way to know which thread (coroutine) executing a Lua script is at the origin of a lua_pushcclosure call?

In order to manage some stuff relative to lua threads (delayed pause/resume, or private thread variables) I need to identify the thread involved in the callback. I know I can get the thread index when creating it by using lua_gettop, but I can't find a way to use it so it helps identifying the thread when a lua_pushcclosure call is issued from a Lua script.

My current system permits nested script calls, so a script can execute other scripts (each nested script call create a new thread with the same lua_state. Thus the lua_state used to get multiple thread entries in the stack.)

I'm using Lua 5.2

Comment: "lua_pushcclosure callback" `lua_pushcclosure` is not a callback. Are you talking about when you *call* that function?

Comment: Yes I am talking about when the function is called from within the lua script. The function exposed through `lua_pushcclosure` can be called from different threads and I need to identify which one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're in a C function that has been called from Lua, and you want to know what thread you're in... just call [`lua_pushthread(L)`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_pushthread).